# Running UI Automation code in BHO

Tags: c++, internet-explorer-11, ui-automation, bho

I have BHO for IE11 and I am running UI Automation code inside it using separate thread.
This code should search particular elements in IE gui. I am using

```
 IUIAutomationElement::FindAll()
```

method to get array of elements which fits simple control type condition.

The problem is resulting array

```
IUIAutomationElementArray
```

is always empty.

The same code executed from console app works as expected.

Why UI Automation does not work from BHO?
Is there some restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE Protection Mode was the reason.
Looks like BHO is very unpopular technology.